# JMeter でResponse Headers をテストする方法

Tags: https

**実現したいこと**

http でアクセスしたときに、https に意図したとおりにリダイレクトするかどうかをテストしたい

**環境**
JMeter 3.2

**試したこと**

1. テスト計画にスレッドグループを追加
2. スレッドグループのサンプラー ＞ HTTPリクエストを追加
3. HTTPリクエストにアサーションを追加
4. スレッドグループに、リスナー ＞ 結果を表示で表示を追加
5. アサーションのテストするフィールドで「 Response Headers 」を選択し、
   パターンマッチングルールに「 一致する 」を選択
   テストパターンに 「 ^Location: https://.+ 」を入力

実行するとテストに失敗してしまいます。

テストパターンに正規表現は使用できないのでしょうか？

テスト対象のドメインが複数あり、今後増えていくことが予定されておりますため、
人力ではなくツールを使ってテストをしたいと考えています。

JMeter は、そもそも「意図したとおりにリダイレクトしているかどうか」のテストには
不向きなのでしょうか？

ご教示いただけると、助かります。
よろしく御願い致します。

Comment: 手元で試してみましたが、確かに「一致する」で試したところ正規表現は動いていませんでした。ドキュメントによると、「一致する（Matches）」はPerl5形式の正規表現（複数行モード）が動作すると書かれてますが、バグがあるかも。
https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion